# Protect ASHX Web Handler from being called by User

Tags: javascript, .net, handler, ashx

I am using a survey ad company to reward users with something they would normally purchase. It is a JavaScript SDK and I can subscribe to the Survey_Finished Event. In that event I call my ASHX handler through AJAX, which passes the username through query string. The handler then gets the username, and updates SQL granting the user their prize.

All a user really has to do is look at the page source, grab the url to the ASHX handler and call it themselves to be able to abuse the system and get as many prizes as they want.

How can I secure this to make sure that my web application is the only thing that is able to call the ASHX handler?

Answer (score 0):

Create a GUID in a table in your database as the key to your discount.  Once the discount is applied lock the discount, and when the order is checked out make discount inactive for that GUID (primary).  I assume this would be done when the ashx handler is called.  That GUID will prevent someone from passing in random numbers.  They will not be able to guess the GUID like an integer key, and the locking mechanism prevents multiple applications of the same discount on several orders.